# Sphinx - Exact match!

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

i have another question!

I have an index with

SPH_MATCH_ALL
SPH_RANK_SPH04

and when i search for the word "ipad" the word "dissIPADor" is comming before the word IPAD alone, how can i make 'ipad' by itself, more relevant than "dissIPADor" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. check that you are using version 2.0.2 or above of sphinx. Version 2.0.1 has a bug in it that doesn't bring single words to the top even though they are an exact match.
2. If you have stemming set up for your morphology in that index, consider removing stemming and adding it as a separate index that inherits from the first one. This way when you search that first index it will only match whole words and you can still use the second index for partials.