# Sphinx search for exact match and then infix matches

Tags: php, search, sphinx, ranking, infix-notation

I am using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) to provide search to a website and I've run across a bit of a snag when returning relevant results.

To keep my question simple, let's assume that I have two fields, @title and @body, which are weighted 100 & 15 respectively.  When I search for small words like the word '**in**' I would like to have it rank exact matches for that search term higher and *then* check for matches to '**in*|*in|*in***' and rank them slightly lower.  Is there any way to have this type of specificity for your searches?

Example results for '**in**':

1. Indian Food
2. **In** The Middle
3. Document about Latin

Some relevant settings are:

In *sphinx.conf*:

```
morphology              = stem_en
charset_type            = utf-8
min_word_len            = 2
min_prefix_len          = 0
min_infix_len           = 2
enable_star             = 1
```

In *search.php*

```
$sp->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 );
$sp->SetRankingMode( SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 );
$sp->SetFieldWeights ( array('title' => 100, 'body' => 15) );
```

---

Also, as a side note: I've also had some instances where partial matches don't even show up in the search results.  For example, I have searched for **Cow** but **Cowboy** does not show up as a result.  I have also searched for **Cowb** and **Cowbo** and it wasn't until I typed **Cowboy** that I received the expected result.  Any thoughts?

---

This question is along the same lines as [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276903/sphinx-exact-match), but I hope I've given a little more detail as to my problem and the things I've tried to warrant a solution.

Comment: Are their any additional items that I could add to help people answer this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like morphologically Cow not related to Cowboy.

You could solve it in two ways:

1. Use wordforms file with Cow > Cowboy
2. As star is enabled you could change query from "Cow" to "Cow*" which will find all words starting with "Cow".

Regard different ranking for "in" and "*in*" I could suggest to have two body fields in index, lets say: body and body_star with the same content from body field.

in search.php

```
$sp->SetRankingMode( SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 );
$sp->SetMatchingMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 );
$sp->SetFieldWeights ( array('title' => 20, 'body' => 15, 'body_start' => 5) );
$sp->Query("@body in @body_star *in* @title in");
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I love reading a solution that seems elegant.  I'll have to play around with the 'cowboy' problem a bit, but I really like your suggestion as to how to solve the 'in' problem.  Great suggestion! (that is... until someone comes along and tells me differently ;)  I'll accept it as the correct answer when I test it assuming it works.

Answer (score 2):

Also you could set expand_keywords option in your config 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-expand-keywords.html
and set ranking mode to SPH_RANK_SPH04
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/08/17/how-sphinx-relevance-ranking-works/